# OPenAI Gym Retro error: "AttributeError: module 'gym.utils.seeding' has no attribute 'hash_seed'"

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, openai-api

I am using WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.4, I create a fresh virtual enviroment using (venv), and install gym-retro as the OpenAI official page states (https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), using the following command:

`pip3 install gym-retro`

I get no error while installing it, and then to test it I run the command (as stated in the getting started page previouly mentioned):

`python3 -m retro.examples.interactive --game Airstriker-Genesis`

And the get the following error:

[image]

Can somebody, please help me?

I have also tested it using the easiest implementation (calling `retro.make("Game-name")`) and I also get the same error.

Comment: see [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/openai/retro) - code is 1 year old (and [retro_env.py](https://github.com/openai/retro/blob/master/retro/retro_env.py) is even 4 years old) and maybe it can't work with the newest [Gym](https://github.com/openai/gym). Maybe they removes `hash_seed` from `Gym`. You may send this problem on GitHub as [issue](https://github.com/openai/retro/issues) but I think you will have to fix this problem on your own in `retro`

Answer (score 7):

Downgrade gym to `0.25.2`. On release `0.26.0` the `hash_seed` was removed.

See: https://github.com/openai/gym/releases/tag/0.26.0

```
$ pip install gym==0.25.2
```